# include file not working c++

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I created a header file to include other headerfiles as a short cut, and it works for almost all of my files, but i have been having problems with  my  file i/o file(it throws errors about not including the files).

**Include file (includes.h)**

```
#ifndef INCLUDES_H_
#define INCLUDES_H_
#include <vector>
#include "html.h"
#include "file.h"
#include <string>
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#endif
```

**File (file.h)**

```
#ifndef FILE_H_
#define FILE_H_
#include "includes.h"
namespace file
{
    int file()
    {
    std::string filename;
    std::cout <<"What would you like to name your file?\n";
    std::cout << "(don't put in the .html)\n";
    std::cin >> filename;
    filename = filename +".html";
    std::ofstream outf(filename);
    return 0;
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: You have a circular include.  `includes.h` should not include `file.h`.

Comment: You'll run into the same problem if you use `#include "includes.h"` in `"html.h"` and `"test.h"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be including `files.h` from within the `files.h` file.

Making a massive includes file seems like a bad idea in general. Everything is included everywhere all the time regardless of whether it is actually needed. This will likely lead to difficult to diagnose errors.

Only include the things you need.

Comment: thank you also it will not allow me to use a string as a filename